# The CiviCRM debug log should not be downloadable - generated .htaccess seems ok

Tags: security, logs

On the `civicrm/a/#/status` the security message *The CiviCRM debug log should not be downloadable* is displayed. And the complaint is correct, I am able to download the log file. But CiviCRM does generate the correct `.htaccess` file in de log directory in the following format

```
<Files "*">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

The used configuration is CiviCRM 5.3.1, Drupal 7.0 and Apache/2.2.15.

The `.htaccess` file is seen by apache. I tested this by making a syntax error in the file. That is reported by the webserver.

Does someone has a hint to get it working again.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the config for the virtual host/Directory does not allow .htaccess override for the Limit directive type, and so is ignoring the Order commands.

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. But thanks @Demerit, you gave the start. I made the assumption that the configuration `.htaccess` is done differently for Apache 2.2. And the drupal `.htaccess` gave some inspiration. I created the following file

```
<Files "*">
  Require all denied
</Files>
```

And that works. Because there is already a .htacess file CiviCRM does not overwrite it.